# Javascript function error : length undefined

Tags: javascript

I am a novice JavaScript user learning about how to code functions in a sustainable and clean way.
But I came across some problems and it throws an error such as console undefined or length undefined and I don't know why it happens like that.

```js
//objects
var lists = [{
    ignore: true,
    accept: true
  },
  {
    meaning: true
  }
];


var start1 = processthings(lists, start);
if (!start1) {
  console.log("wrong! start it first!")
};
var dictionary1 = processthings(lists, dictionary);
if (!dictionary1) {
  console.log("look it up!")
};

//comprehensive process function
function processthings(lists, cfunctions) {
  for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    if (cfunctions(lists[i])) {
      return true;
    };

    return false;
  };

};

//each function : number 1
function start(element) {
  return (element.ignore == true);
};


// each functon : number 2
function dictionary(element) {
  return (element.meaning);
};
```

Comment: Click "Run code snippet", your code is not generating any error.  Please edit your question in such a way that you are able to reproduce the issue.  Otherwise we do not have a way to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop in function *processthings* will never iterate through the entire list. The function will always return after the first iteration.

I am not sure whether that is done intentionally or not. But I think the function should be modified as below -

```
//comprehensive process function
function processthings (lists,cfunctions){
    var flag = false;
    for (var i=0; i< lists.length; i++){
        if (cfunctions(lists[i])){
            flag = true;
            break;
        };
     };
     return flag;   
};
```

See the working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/52kr83c4/8/)